# TestNg output on console

Tags: testng

How would I display the following log in Eclipse on the terminal when I run the [testng](/questions/tagged/testng) program from the console?

```
PASSED: session("liferay", [liferay.xml], "10.95.102.5", "2")
PASSED: session("tomcat_linux", [tomcat_linux.xml], "10.95.102.35", "1")
```

Answer (score 2):

If the above statements are part of `Reporter.log()` Then you just need to pass one more parameter something like this `Reporter.log("message",true)` If it is a part of TestNG logging then just increase the verbose to level 10. If you are running through TestNg.xml then in the suite node you can find verbose attribute. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: If you find it useful then please accept the answer